# Slow "hide" an element while moving it toward another element on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think allrecipes.com used to do this when you favorited a recipe, the thumbnail would sort of fly up to your recipe box and then disappear

The slow/fast hide shrinks to a point, but I'd like it to do that same effect by move toward another element on the page instead of "the beginning of the line" default effect

Here is the code I'm using now from the [jQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com/hide/):

```
// Hide box on click
$( "#hideBox" ).click(function() {
$( "#box" ).hide( "fast", function() {
});
});
```

Comment: You're going to want to use jquery animate for that http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use .animate instead. Have a look at the documentation, [here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). :)